# Transpose in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transpose

I imported the data from csv file with pandas. I want to split the column which includes 50 (0 to 49) values into 5 rows each having ten values. Can anyone tell me how i can do this transpose in form of pandas frame?

Let me rephrase what i said:

I attached the data that i have. I wanted to select the second column, and split it into two rows each having 10 values.

That is the code i have done so far:(I couldn't get the picture of 50 rows so i have only put 20 rows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EuiW.jpg))

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('...csv')
df.iloc[:50,:2]
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(mycolumn=np.random.randint(10, size=50)))
```

*using `numpy` and `reshape`'ing, ignoring indices*

```
pd.DataFrame(df.mycolumn.values.reshape(5, -1))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  2  7  3  8  7  0  6  8  6
1  0  2  0  4  9  7  3  2  4  3
2  3  6  7  7  4  5  3  7  5  9
3  8  7  6  4  7  6  2  6  6  5
4  2  8  7  5  8  4  7  6  1  5

​
```

Comment: what is "mycolumn" here?

Comment: @Shelly you didn't really say much about your dataframe... I decided to make up an example that demonstrates the principle.  Either you can generalize this to your situation or you can give more details and I can tailor it to your needs.

Comment: I have editted my initial post to better illustrate what i want